# David Lynch's Maphilight - Highlight All

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello and good day to everyone.

I wanna ask if there is a way for me to highlight every area of a map.

This is the scenario... There's a US map and there's a reset button. All the states' names are covered, meaning that every area is already highlighted. Clicking on one of them 'dehighlights' them, revealing their name.

Those things are already functioning properly. However, I am having trouble with the reset button.

Basically, I want the reset button to cover every names again, excluding the still covered ones (because, well, they're not clicked/revealed yet).

Google isn't being helpful for me on this issue, and the Maphilight documentation on the site...isn't really well-documented.

I hope someone can help me on this one. Thanks~

Comment: what does your code look like so far?

Comment: I simply copied and edited an existing example on JSfiddle to fit my issue...
http://jsfiddle.net/204v7k02/

As you can see, at the start, the two areas are highlighted. Click one and it will 'unhighlight'. What I need to achieve is when the user clicks the reset button, the two areas will be highlighted again.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind~ I figured it out! :D

I inserted this code inside [$.fn.maphilight = function(opts)]'s [return this.each(function()]

```
reset_hilight = function() {
    var mapCount = document.getElementsByTagName("area").length;
    var i = 1;


    while (i <= mapCount) {
        var AllAreas = $('#hlight' + i).data('maphilight') || {};

        AllAreas.alwaysOn = true;
        $('#hlight' + i).data('maphilight', AllAreas).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');

        i++;
    }
}
```

So now, whenever I click the reset button, all the areas will be highlited once again. :D